# Redirect url using .htaccess (Multiple special characters)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, http-referer

There are lots of posts here about redirect using htaccess, but i am unable to find one for me.

I want to redirect following url to 404 page. But i am facing problems because of special characters in it.

I want following urls to a my 404 page.

http://www.site1.com/i.php?id=303&vis=1&url=http://www.site2.com
http://www.site1.com/cgi-bin/a2/out.cgi?id=49&u=http://www.site 2.com

to http://www.site1.com/404

Can anyone shed some light ?

Comment: please post some code that you tried

Comment: I have tried the below one, but no effects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?site1.\com/i\.php?id=303&vis=1&url=http://www\.site2.\com/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.site1.com/404 [R,L]

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=303&vis=1&url=http://www\.site2\.com$
RewriteRule ^i\.php$ /404? [L,R=404]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=49&u=http://www\.site2\.com$
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/a2/out\.cgi$ /404? [L,R=404]
```

Comment: It seems that the R=404 is causing the internat server error, you will have to change it to R=302 and then generate a 404 header response in your 404 error page

Comment: R=4XX is only supported beginning with Apache 2.X